# Best to way to add up numbers by ids

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a file, which has 2 columns.

```
12,1
12,2
11,3
11,2
```

I want to add the second column by the first column.
The output should look like this

```
12,3
11,5
```

Is there any easy way to do this on Linux environments (on command line)?

Comment: In every language you will implement this one way or another. Which of them do you want?

Comment: I want to do this using script languages such as python or bash script

Comment: Is output order important (12->11 vs. 11->12)?

Comment: no. order is not important

Comment: There are hundreds of such languages. (OK, dozens relevant). That makes finding "the best way" next to impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat file
12,1
12,2
11,3
11,2
```

Here is an `awk` approach:

```
$ awk -F, '$1 { a[$1]+=$2 } END { for (i in a) { printf "%s,%d\n", i, a[i] } }' file
11,5
12,3
```

And here one in `bash`:

```
$ cat ./id.sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=','
while read id value; do
        [ -n "${id}" ] || continue
        (( a[id] += value ))
done < file

for id in "${!a[@]}"; do
        echo "${id},${a[${id}]}"
done

$ ./id.sh
11,5
12,3
```

They both work by the same principle - they read line by line with their field/input separator set to `,` and assemble an array indexed by the first column - the values of the second column are just summed up. When all the hard work is done, we print the array back.

Answer (score 1):

In a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %sum;
my %pos;

my $i = 0;

while(<>){
   chomp;
   my($x,$y) = split/,/;
   $pos{$x} = $i unless exists $pos{$x};
   $sum{$x} += $y;
   $i++;       
}

my @keys = sort { $pos{$a} <=> $pos{$b} } keys %pos;
for my $key(@keys){
   print "$key,$sum{$key}\n"
}
```

Put this in a script, and put your number in a file, then run:

```
perl $script $file
```

This also preserves order.  Python has a similar structure.